# Security of Samsung Remote Test Lab

Tags: android, testing, android-testing, samsung-mobile

I am developing an Android application and I am testing it with `Samsung's "REMOTE TEST LAB"` service. The tool is nice to test the application on different Samsung devices.

My application is not released yet and I am worried whether it will be safe to test the application using `"REMOTE TEST LAB"`. I am concerned about whether application will be accessible to other user of this service if I forgot to uninstall the application from the device of `"REMOTE TEST LAB"` service.

It would be helpful if anyone can provide additional thoughts/suggestions.

Thank you.